# After changing SMTP port from 25 to 587 I can send, but now I don't receive emails

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-bounces

I configured Postfix, after a time I discovered I am blocked from sending emails because my network is on a blacklist (it's a dynamic IP). So, sometimes Outlook does not connect to send (still gets the mails). Then I changed the SMTP on the master file and I set port 587 on this way:

```
587      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

The problem is now I can't receive, I get these errors:

> The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect

On my domain manager I set the A register to point to his own IP, and the MX to point to my domain name (the MX is mydomain.com, not mail.mydomain.com, but all was configured this way with Postfix).

I don't understand what could be wrong, any idea of this issue?

Comment: Probably, outer SMTP servers or relays merely don't know how to connect to your SMTP server. Maybe they try to connect to port 25. You can clear it out by issuing `tcpdump -nnn -i ethX port 25`. Then try to send e-mail to your domain from another ISP. If there will be any output, then I'm right.

Comment: it returns (SIOCGIFHWADDR: No such device)

Comment: You should be root or run `sudo tcpdump -nnn -i ethX port 25`. And do not forget to replace `ethX` with actual name of your WAN interface, e.g. eth0 or eth1 or anything-you-have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To receive emails from other servers, you *need* to be listening on port 25. Port 587 is the *submission* port, intended for clients to submit mail for delivery. Other mail servers will never try to connect to this port.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....do u know how do enable this listening?

Comment: @user156355 - you undo what you did to switch to port 587.